# application not work correctly after change type to windows application

Tags: c#, console

i created a C# console application to upload a certain file in computer to web server.it works fine.but i want to hide my console application as well.
then i changed my application type from property panel to windows application .and now i realize that it doesn't work correctly ..it still do everything expect uploading part.when it was console type it do upload process correctly and it running until i hit enter because i add console.readline();  to it.but now when i run in visual studio it auto stops running before upload successfully .i can't realize why ..need a help

my uploading codes are given below.

```
public static Boolean upload()
{
    Console.WriteLine("uploading");
    text_a("uplading");
    String file = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + 
        "\\micro_db\\zipper\\keys.zip";

    String url = "http://mysite/upload.php";

    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(UploadFileCallback2);

        // Specify a progress notification handler.
        //client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
        client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "POST", file);
        Console.WriteLine("File upload started.");
        text_a("file upload started");
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        text_a(e.ToString());
        return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating three projects:

the first project will be your "service" project that will just be a plain class library that exposes a class to do the `Upload()` method.

the second project will be your console application.  add a reference to the first project you created and create a new instance of the class from your service project.

the third can be a windows project.  this will also take a reference to the service project. New up the class just like you did in the console application.

this way you can run your console application or your windows application by just right clicking the desired project and selecting debug.

You cannot just switch from a console to a windows application type without doing the plumbing to make it work.